# automapper memberList parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio, automapper

In AutoMapper when you use generic version of Mapper.CreateMap you can easly ignore it by adding .ForMember at the end:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewItem>().ForMember(x=>x.Id,opt=>opt.Ignore);
```

How to do it for non generic types like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Customer.GetType(),CustomerViewItem().GetType(), MemberList memberList);
```

Comment: What properties do you need ignore?

Comment: @FelipeOriani I would like to ignore Id property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

`Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(Customer), typeof(CustomerViewItem)).ForMember("Id", opt => opt.Ignore());`